# How to find mostly accessed/used tables in Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How to find mostly accessed and used  tables in Postgresql database?

Answer (score 13):

most often reads:

```
select schemaname,relname,seq_scan,idx_scan 
from pg_stat_all_tables 
order by coalesce(seq_scan,0)+coalesce(idx_scan,0) desc 
limit 5;
```

same can be done for inserts `n_tup_ins`, updates `n_tup_upd`,`n_tup_hot_upd` and deltes: `n_tup_del`.

or most accessed in general by summaryzing them all, like `order by coalesce(seq_scan,0)+coalesce(idx_scan,0)+coalesce(n_tup_ins,0) + ...` etc

Comment: What timeframe are the results calculated over? For example, if the results show that table foo has 28 seq scan's, is that over the last week? Month? Since the creation of the table?

Comment: since relation created or last reset (`pg_stat_reset()`) I suppose

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you count “accesed and used”.

If the number of index and sequential scans is a good measure for you, you could use:

```
SELECT schemaname, relname,
       COALESCE(seq_scan, 0) + COALESCE(idx_scan, 0) nr_accesses
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
ORDER BY 3 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Alternatively, you could use `seq_tup_read + idx_tup_fetch` if the number of accessed rows is a better measure for you.